# var_dump outputting string('**') "array"

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I am using a foreach loop and a var_dump but the var_dump from the following code outputs something strange. How do I get rid of the pre-prended sring() and quotation marks?

```
$dir = 'url/dir/dir/';    
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg'); 

$images = array();

foreach ($images_array as $image) {
    $images[] = str_replace($dir, '', $image);   
}


var_dump(implode(',', $images));
```

Output:

> string(51) "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg"

Comment: If in doubt, consult php.net on what you're using. It's very easy to search, just go "php.net/var_dump" and it takes you to the page. For printing you should use echo or print. If you're new, check over the manual section on the basics -- it's all on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `var_dump` does - it prints the datatype and the length. If you want to output just the string use

```
echo implode(',', $images);
```

Comment: Never trust what you see in the browser's rendered output when debugging PHP scripts. Always look at the page source, which shows the raw un-interpreted output.

Answer (score 3):

`var_dump` isn't outputting anything 'strange'.  That is what it's supposed to do.  It's for debugging, not for echoing.

Just `echo` the string you want:

```
echo implode(',', $images);
```

Answer (score 3):

`var_dump` returns you type of variable and all information about it.
If you use it with HTML `<pre>`

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($images);
```

it will print for you an array with all elements in new lines.

If:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(implode(',', $images));
```

it returns string.
And also shows you that it is a string.

If you just want to print value, use `echo`:

```
echo implode(',', $images);
```